# JOOQ selectQuery for Record5

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I'm new to JOOQ.

And I need to use SelectQuery and return Result, but return type of it is Record. Is it possible to use selectQuery with Record5? Or is there another solution?

```
    SelectQuery<Record> query = db.selectQuery();
    query.addSelect(WARE.NAME, RECEIPTITEM.SALEPRICE, RECEIPTITEM.QUANTITY, RECEIPT.TSCCREATED, WARE.WARECATEGORYID);
    query.addFrom(RECEIPT
            .join(RECEIPTITEM).on(RECEIPT.ID.eq(RECEIPTITEM.RECEIPTID))
            .join(OUTLET).on(OUTLET.ID.eq(RECEIPT.OUTLETID))
            .join(WARE).on(WARE.ID.eq(RECEIPTITEM.WAREID)));
    query.addConditions(RECEIPT.TSCCREATED.between(start, end)
            .and(OUTLET.OWNERID.eq(ownerId)));
    if (outletId != null) {
        query.addConditions(RECEIPT.OUTLETID.eq(outletId));
    }
    if (merchantId != null) {
        query.addConditions(RECEIPT.MERCHID.eq(merchantId));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a `SelectQuery<Record5<...>>` type with jOOQ.

The reason for this is the fact that `SelectQuery` ([which is part of the model API](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/dsl-and-non-dsl/)) allows you to keep adding new columns to it via [`SelectQuery.addSelect()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SelectQuery.html#addSelect-org.jooq.SelectField...-) (which you've done yourself). Each such call would invalidate the `Record5<...>` type.

However, you don't have to use the model API to construct dynamic SQL, if the dynamic parts are only additional conditions. You can rewrite your query like this:

```
Condition condition = RECEIPT.TSCCREATED.between(start, end)
    .and(OUTLET.OWNERID.eq(ownerId));

if (outletId != null) {
    condition = condition.and(RECEIPT.OUTLETID.eq(outletId));
}
if (merchantId != null) {
    condition = condition.and(RECEIPT.MERCHID.eq(merchantId));
}

Select<Record5<String, BigDecimal, Integer, Timestamp, Long>> select =
db.select(
       WARE.NAME, 
       RECEIPTITEM.SALEPRICE, 
       RECEIPTITEM.QUANTITY, 
       RECEIPT.TSCCREATED, 
       WARE.WARECATEGORYID)
  .from(RECEIPT
      .join(RECEIPTITEM).on(RECEIPT.ID.eq(RECEIPTITEM.RECEIPTID))
      .join(OUTLET).on(OUTLET.ID.eq(RECEIPT.OUTLETID))
      .join(WARE).on(WARE.ID.eq(RECEIPTITEM.WAREID)))
  .where(condition);
```